# Form creates multiple commit buttons in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

i got a form which looks like this:

```
<h1>Title: <%= @task.title %></h1>
    Dates: <% @dates.map do |date|  %>
    <%= form_tag("/responses/create/", :method => "post", :id => @task) do %>
          <%= date.task_date %> <%= check_box_tag  "response_checkbox", date.task_date %>
        <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

what i want is a list of checkboxes where the user can select one and then submit the form with one button. but the form produces one submit button for every object and i can't figure out why! working on this for hours now ...

here is the html output:

```
<h1>Title: Weihnachtsball</h1>
Dates:
<form id="#<Task:0x000001067a6320>" method="post" action="/responses/create/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
<input type="hidden" value="OaDIn2B0yHVBAY9z7F0IOdiULu5GiqlSJV5+Ft92tbw=" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
2014-11-10 11:11:00 UTC
<input id="response_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2014-11-10 11:11:00 UTC" name="response_checkbox">
</form>
<form id="#<Task:0x000001067a6320>" method="post" action="/responses/create/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
<input type="hidden" value="OaDIn2B0yHVBAY9z7F0IOdiULu5GiqlSJV5+Ft92tbw=" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
2014-11-23 12:14:00 UTC
<input id="response_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2014-11-23 12:14:00 UTC" name="response_checkbox">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="commit">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate through dates inside the `form_tag`

```
<h1>Title: <%= @task.title %></h1>
<%= form_tag("/responses/create/", :method => "post", :id => @task) do %>
  Dates: <% @dates.map do |date|  %>
    <%= date.task_date %> <%= radio_button_tag "response_checkbox", date.task_date %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
<% end %>
```

should be ok.

#### Update

I think `radio_button_tag` is better for you case. After all you want the user to select **one** box.

Comment: thanks a lot! that fixes the problem with the button! but how can i access the different values in the params hash now? as a response i only get {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OaDIn2B0yHVBAY9z7F0IOdiULu5GiqlSJV5+Ft92tbw=", "response"=>"2014-11-23 12:14:00 UTC", "commit"=>"Add", "controller"=>"responses", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: the problem was that there was only one entry in the params hash as shown above - my solution looks like this: <%= check_box_tag  "response_checkbox#{date.id}", date.task_date %></p>